# How to refresh current frame in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I want to refresh my current for when selecting a new background image, the image will instantly changed when i press save/OK button.
I've trying to using `gotoAndStop("frame1");` then `gotoAndStop("frame2");` in a function, it works but it disturbing my other function.
Can anyone tell me how to refresh frame properly ?
Thanks..

Comment: How are you loading you new image ? Normally you don't need to refresh anything to see it.

Comment: Most probably each time a new instance of image is created which needs to be `addChild()`'ed to stage in order to be seen, ang going forward and back to the first frame just does it. In that case a bunch of loaded images will be stacked.

Comment: The image is already there, the setting only set the visibility of the images. So when i press save button, the visiblity of the images will changed, but it's not changed instatly, i must go to the other frame for the image visibility check function to work.